# Determining if a bi-weekly schedule matches a given date

Tags: ruby

I'm creating multiple `Schedule` objects, which have a `started_at` datetime which begins on Mondays.

I have `Location` objects which have a `visit_frequency`. Some of these are set to `:bi_weekly`, in which case I only need to see them every other week.

However, things don't always go according to plan and sometimes `Location`s are visited more or less often than the need to.

Right now I'm doing

```
Location.all.each do |location|
...
elsif location.frequency.rate == 'biweekly'
    if (@schedule.start_date - location.last_visit_date) > 7
      schedule_for_week location
    end
```

The problem is, if I make a `Schedule` more than 7 days from now, the `Location`'s `last_visit_date` will ALWAYS be > 7 days. I need to calculate if it falls into a bi-weekly rate.

Example:

Location 1 visit_frequency set to :bi_weekly
Location 1 is visited on Week 1
Week 2 Schedule Generated -- Location 1 is left out because it is within 7 days
Week 3 Schedule Generated -- Location 1 is included because it is within 7 days
Week 4 Schedule Generated -- Location 1 is included because it is within 7 days

The last line should not have happened. Location 1 should not be included because it was visited on Week 1 and scheduled for Week 3.

How can I calculate if a week is within a bi-weekly frequency succintly? I"m guessing I need to use beginning_of_week?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your question, I believe this would do it:

```
require 'date'

def schedule?(sched_start_date, last_visit_date)
  (sched_start_date - last_visit_date) % 14 > 7
end

sched_start_date = Date.parse("2014-12-29")
  #=> #<Date: 2014-12-29 ((2457021j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)> a Monday

schedule?(sched_start_date, Date.parse("2014-12-04")) #=> true
schedule?(sched_start_date, Date.parse("2014-12-14")) #=> false
schedule?(sched_start_date, Date.parse("2014-12-20")) #=> true
schedule?(sched_start_date, Date.parse("2014-12-23")) #=> false
```